# Can tab names in FileZilla be customized?

Tags: filezilla, tabs, title

FileZilla tabs titles contain multiple pieces of information—site manager entry name, username and hostname. This can result in quite a long tab. Is there any way of customizing what is shown? In particular, can some of the info be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

That title format is hardcoded, at least in the free version of FileZilla:
https://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/trunk/src/interface/state.cpp?revision=9515&view=markup#l1406